# Two versions of [] operator for rvalue and lvalue cases

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have implemented a collection of `int`s. I would like to have to versions of the `[]` operator:

1. One that returns an `int` used when a `rvalue` is needed. For example, when user tries to read a given position in the collection. If element on this position doesn't exist, it should throw exception.
2. One that returns an `int&` used when a `lvalue` is expected, for storing a value at a given position. If element at this position doesn't exist, function should allocate space for it.

What is an idiomatic way of doing so?

Comment: But when do you expect each to be called? And how does the calling code choose?

Comment: You have to return a proxy object with appropriate conversions/operator overloads that implement the behavior you are seeking.

Comment: No one is doing it, so there's no idiomatic way.

Comment: The Standard Library associative containers like `map::operator[]` *default-construct* a new element if the key is not found, and return a reference to the (now always existing) element. There are additional `find` member functions that return an iterator to an existing element if the key is found, and an iterator to the past-the-end sentinel if the key is not found.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why you need it - AFAIK, lvalue can be converted to rvalue, so one `int& operator[]` should be enough.

It's not possible to have two functions with same name and same argument list, even when them have different returned type.

If you really need two methods, you can use `operator()` in one of the applications.

Answer (score 0):

You need an helper type that implements assign and convert

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible because any expression in C++ must stand on its own merit, it does not change its type or properties depending on what context it is used in.

So if someone writes `yourobject[5]`  then this must resolve to the same thing regardless of whether they go on to assign to it as part of a larger expression.